# Font is not loading when deployed

Tags: css, angular

I have created an angular app which loads perfectly fine in local environment. all the styles and fonts are getting applied. but when I deploy it the font is not loading. couldn't figure it out why, it didn't show any error or warning message in the console.

I'm importing all the css styles in `angular.json` file like below

[image]

`demo4.css` has the styles that I need. I placed the `demo4` file in the first, middle and last , nothing happened and didn't made any sense !!

When running locally,

[image]

When deployed,

[image]

I was banging my head for days. What am I missing?

**Update #1**

This is how it looks like when I build `ng build --prod`

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? (In your browser, and on your server)

Comment: yes. ran in different browsers too.

Comment: What do your output css files look like when you ng-build? Can you find your code there? If you look for the css font family in your code in your browser, can you find it anywhere?

Comment: Have you used the `@font-face {
     font-family:` in your demo4.css? Or nothing from your demo4.css is reflected?

Comment: A good start would be to check the Network tab in your devtools, and filter on Font requests. Do you see fontello on the list? Does it have a 200 status, or is it something wrong with the paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have run into this [logged issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10855):

The only workaround available is to Add Google fonts `@import` tag in the `header` of every SCSS used. Or import first the fonts from a different `css/SCSS` file

**EDIT**
Or import your font in index.html

Comment: Have you used the `@font-face { font-family:` in your demo4.css? Or nothing from your demo4.css is reflected? Are your fonts loaded successfully in browser?

Comment: No, i'm using `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,400,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700');`

Comment: May be this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10855   
In every scss file that will use Google fonts, put the @import tag in the header ...

Unfortunately for now it's the only way I found to work around the problem, since adding the @import in global style does not work during the build`

Comment: Yep, this is a known issue. now i'm importing the fonts in the `index.html` file and its working