# Vercel deploy: font is not loading correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

Locally my site run with the fonts up.

I needed to deploy it twice to get the fonts correctly (without changing any css code)

[image]

But now, in my smartphone it's not working yet:

[image]

I put the fonts include in index.js (main file) but does not work.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Vabulous';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('./fonts/Vabulous.ttf')
}
```

I followed this thread: [Font is not loading when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559019/font-is-not-loading-when-deployed) of angular but it does not work.

Maybe it will work soon but I want to understand why it does not working now. (it's not cache, since I had never opened this site on my smartphone).

Comment: Are you sure that the ttf file is loaded in the right place?

Comment: yeah, I'm able to download the font if I write in chrome apipool.io/fonts/fontname.ttf,
but now it is working. I separated the CSS code in a specific file and import it on my _app.js and it worked. I don't know why wasn't working on smartphones. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Its solved itself. I think that was cache or something. You can access the url and see that now it works. https://apipool.io